# jquery code works in Mozilla but not on other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Good Day to all the people of stackoverflow! Nuff said, anyway I've been familiarizing myself with jquery. My code works on my default browser Mozilla but on other browsers like chrome or internet the page just refreshes.

This is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    function activateregp(){                            
        $.get('inc/registration.php', function(data) {              
            $('#content').append(data);                             
            $(function () {
                $('#registration_form').submit(function () {
                    if($(this).valid()) {                           
                        $('.reg_process').remove();                         
                        alert("A");                         
                        activatecom();                              
                        alert("B");                         
                    }                                                                                               
                });
            });    
        });                                         
    }

    function activatecom(){                
        $.get('inc/community.html', function(data) {
            $('#content').append(data);                 
            $("#com_but").click(function(){    
                $(".com_process").remove();                 
                activatehelp();        
            });    
        });
    }

    activateregp();     
});
```

My index.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main_func.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="main_con">
  <div id="step_process"><img id ="step_img" src="images/step5.png" width="588" height="49" />
    <div id="rtext">Register</div>
    <div id="uptext">Upload Pic</div>
    <div id="eptext">Edit Profile</div>
    <div id="pstext">Privacy Settings</div>
    <div id="ctext">Community</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="title_step">
      <div id="title">Register</div>
    </div>





  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the php file to append

```
<div class="reg_process" id="reg_part">
  <div id="namelabel" >Displayed Name:</div>
  <div id="dnametext">Kevin Mark Montesclaros</div>
  <form id="registration_form" action="" method="post" >
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Title:</td>
          <td><select name="data[User][question]" id="studenttitle" style="width:50px;" required="required">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="1">Mr.</option>
              <option value="2">Mrs.</option>
              <option value="2">Ms.</option>
              <option value="2">Dr.</option>
            </select>
            <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" style="height:14px; width:14px; margin:5px;" />
            <label for="checkbox">Display Title in place of your First Name </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>First Name: <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></td>
          <td><label for="firstname"></label>
            <input name="data[User][firstname]" id="firstname" type="text" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Middle Name:</td>
          <td><label for="middlename"></label>
            <input name="data[User][middle_name]" id="middlename"  type="text" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last Name: <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></td>
          <td><label for="lastname"></label>
            <input name="data[User][lastname]" style="color: rgb(53, 180, 222);" id="lastname" type="text" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email: <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></td>
          <td><label for="email3"></label>
            <input name="data[User][email]" id="email3" style="color: rgb(53, 180, 222);" type="email" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Choose Password: <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></td>
          <td><label for="password"></label>
            <input name="data[User][password]" id="password" type="password" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Confirm Password:</td>
          <td><label for="password2"></label>
            <input name="data[User][confirmPassword]" id="password2" type="password" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question: &nbsp;<a href="#" class="settings_question"></a></td>
          <td><select name="data[User][question]" id="UserQuestion" required="required">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="1">What was your childhood nickname?</option>
              <option value="2">Who was your childhood hero?</option>
              <option value="3">Where were you when you had your first kiss?</option>
              <option value="4">What was the last name of your favorite teacher?</option>
              <option value="5">When you were young, what did you want to be when you grew up?</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Secret Answer: &nbsp;<a href="#" class="settings_question"></a></td>
          <td><label for="secret"></label>
            <input name="data[User][answer]" id="secret" type="text" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Timezone:&nbsp;<a href="#" class="settings_question"></a></td>
          <td><select name="data[User][country]" id="DropDownTimezone" required="required">
              <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
              <option value="AL">Albania</option>
              <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
              <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
              <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
              <option value="AO">Angola</option>
              <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
              <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
              <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
              <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
              <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
              <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
              <option value="AU">Australia</option>
              <option value="AT">Austria</option>
              <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
              <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
              <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
              <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
              <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
              <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
              <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
              <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
              <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
              <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
              <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
              <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
              <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
              <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
              <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
              <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
              <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
              <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
              <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
              <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
              <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
              <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
              <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
              <option value="CA">Canada</option>
              <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
              <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
              <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
              <option value="TD">Chad</option>
              <option value="CL">Chile</option>
              <option value="CN">China</option>
              <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
              <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
              <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
              <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
              <option value="CG">Congo</option>
              <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
              <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
              <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
              <option value="CI">Cote DIvoire</option>
              <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
              <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
              <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
              <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
              <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
              <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
              <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
              <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
              <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
              <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
              <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
              <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
              <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
              <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
              <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
              <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
              <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
              <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
              <option value="FI">Finland</option>
              <option value="FR">France</option>
              <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
              <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
              <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
              <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
              <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
              <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
              <option value="DE">Germany</option>
              <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
              <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
              <option value="GR">Greece</option>
              <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
              <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
              <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
              <option value="GU">Guam</option>
              <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
              <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
              <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
              <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
              <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
              <option value="HM">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
              <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
              <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
              <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
              <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
              <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
              <option value="IN">India</option>
              <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
              <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
              <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
              <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
              <option value="IL">Israel</option>
              <option value="IT">Italy</option>
              <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
              <option value="JP">Japan</option>
              <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
              <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
              <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
              <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
              <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic Peoples Republic of</option>
              <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
              <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
              <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
              <option value="LA">Lao Peoples Democratic Republic</option>
              <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
              <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
              <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
              <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
              <option value="LY">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
              <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
              <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
              <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
              <option value="MO">Macao</option>
              <option value="MK">Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
              <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
              <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
              <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
              <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
              <option value="ML">Mali</option>
              <option value="MT">Malta</option>
              <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
              <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
              <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
              <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
              <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
              <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
              <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
              <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
              <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
              <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
              <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
              <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
              <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
              <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
              <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
              <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
              <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
              <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
              <option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option>
              <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
              <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
              <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
              <option value="NE">Niger</option>
              <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
              <option value="NU">Niue</option>
              <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
              <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
              <option value="NO">Norway</option>
              <option value="OM">Oman</option>
              <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
              <option value="PW">Palau</option>
              <option value="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
              <option value="PA">Panama</option>
              <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
              <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
              <option value="PE">Peru</option>
              <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
              <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
              <option value="PL">Poland</option>
              <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
              <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
              <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
              <option value="RE">Reunion</option>
              <option value="RO">Romania</option>
              <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
              <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
              <option value="SH">Saint Helena</option>
              <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
              <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
              <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
              <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
              <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
              <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
              <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
              <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
              <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
              <option value="CS">Serbia and Montenegro</option>
              <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
              <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
              <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
              <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
              <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
              <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
              <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
              <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
              <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
              <option value="ES">Spain</option>
              <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
              <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
              <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
              <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
              <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
              <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
              <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
              <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
              <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
              <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
              <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
              <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
              <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
              <option value="TG">Togo</option>
              <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
              <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
              <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
              <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
              <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
              <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
              <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
              <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
              <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
              <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
              <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
              <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
              <option value="US">United States</option>
              <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
              <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
              <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
              <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
              <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
              <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
              <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option>
              <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.s.</option>
              <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
              <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
              <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
              <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
              <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style=" margin-top:10px; font-size:small;"><span style="color:#a4a4a4;">By clicking the button, you agree to our</span> <a href="/pages/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> <span style="color:#a4a4a4;">&amp;</span> <a href="/pages/terms">Terms of Use</a></div>
    <div style="margin-top:5px;  font-size:small; color:#a4a4a4; font-style:italic;">*Content will be constantly scanned routinely by the system to avoid abuse</div>
    <div class="reg_process" id="regsubmit">
      <input id="reg_but" value="Create my Account" type="submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

To explain my code, it is used for a registration page, it will append a php file, and when the form is valid on submit, it will remove the .reg_process id and append the next php file.

I already did a lot of research and some messing around stuffs but I still fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$.get('inc/registration.php', function(data) {              
        $('#content').append(data);                             
        $(function () {
            $('#registration_form').submit(function () {
                if($(this).valid()) {                           
                    $('.reg_process').remove();                         
                    alert("A");                         
                    activatecom();                              
                    alert("B");                         
                }                                                                                               
            });
        });    
    });
```

to:

```
$.get('inc/registration.php', function(data) {              
        $('#content').append(data);                             

        $('#registration_form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).valid()) {                           
                $('.reg_process').remove();                         
                alert("A");                         
                activatecom();                              
                alert("B");                         
            }                                                                                               
        });                
    });
```

This inner `$(function()` call won't be run as the document has already loaded.

Also note the `e.preventDefault()`. This will stop the form from submitting as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you realise or weather you've posted the whole code, but you're missing a few closing brackets, sometimes it helps to format your code properly so you can see the mistakes, Some browsers can skim over these problems and run just fine, others, not so good, but give this a try.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function activateregp(){
        $.get('inc/registration.php', function(data) {
            $('#content').append(data);
            $(function () {
                $('#registration_form').submit(function () {
                    if($(this).valid()) {
                        $('.reg_process').remove();
                        alert("A");
                        activatecom();  
                        alert("B");
                    };
                });
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: yeah I didn't posted the whole code for sake of a short post. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1):

unclear still about what you wanna do here
try remove the `$(function(){})` inside the `activetGrp` function
so from

```
$(function () {
                $('#registration_form').submit(function () {
                    if($(this).valid()) {

                        $('.reg_process').remove();

                        alert("A");

                        activatecom();  

                        alert("B");

                    }
```

to

```
        $('#registration_form').submit(function () {
            if($(this).valid()) {

                $('.reg_process').remove();

                alert("A");

                activatecom();  

                alert("B");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of your code. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // registration_form submit
    $('#registration_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop page reload
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $('.reg_process').remove();
            alert("A");
            activatecom();
            alert("B");
        }
    });

    // #com_but click event
    // from code it seems this should be
    // a delegate event, if not delegate event
    // this just user
    // $('#com_but').click(..);

    $("#content").on('click', '#com_but', function() {
        $(".com_process").remove();
        activatehelp();
    });

    // activateregp method
    function activateregp() {
        $.get('inc/registration.php', function(data) {
            $('#content').append(data);
        });
    }
    // activatecom method
    function activatecom() {
        $.get('inc/community.html', function(data) {
            $('#content').append(data);

        });
    }
    // inital call to activateregp() at page load
    activateregp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this part out of the activateregp() functionis:

```
    $('#registration_form').submit(function () {
                if($(this).valid()) {                           
                    $('.reg_process').remove();                         
                    alert("A");                         
                    activatecom();                              
                    alert("B");                         
                }                                                                                               
            });
```

and this:

```
$("#com_but").click(function(){    
            $(".com_process").remove();                 
            activatehelp();        
        });
```